# Program to gather statistics on disk activity

Tags: .net, performance, performancecounter

I'm benchmarking our application's database performance with various settings in order to determine which values give us the best performance.  The metric I need to track is called `Active Time` in Windows 7's Resource Monitor, on the `Disk` tab, under `Storage`.  The values displayed for this statistic in Resource Monitor are instantaneous.  I need to compute rolling 1 minute averages like they do for other statistics that are included in the graphs.

Is there a program out there that I can download that does this?  If not, what APIs would I need to call to get that value?

Comment: Why are you not using stopwatch to measure best performance?

Comment: It's not about how long the operation takes (it takes hours); it's about how busy the disk drive gets during the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set up performance counters in windows to record what you want. This can be done from [inside your program](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8590/An-Introduction-To-Performance-Counters) or have windows track it from inside [Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx) (`perfmon.exe`) (so your program does not need to be running for it to be recording, just set up a [Data Collector Set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749337.aspx) and you can have it record on whatever schedule you want) then have your program parse the logs at a later date.

Comment: @ScottChamerlain:  Thanks.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Question:  Are the performance counters defined the same way across different versions of Windows?  Specifically, is the Physical Disk % Disk Time counter the same in Windows XP, 7 & 8?

Comment: 95% sure that they are the same.